What's the best Q&A to promote to the canonical answer for "advance fee scam" questions?
We have been getting a lot of questions about variations of "Do I have to pay an advance fee to unlock a withdrawal/wallet?". I'd like us to designate a question and answer pair to the canonical Q&A on the matter so we can just close any new instances as a duplicate of that.
I'm considering RedGrittyBrick's answer here as a potential candidate:
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/103018/5406
I suggest that we would convert the question to a community wiki that we would then edit to introduce the topic broadly, then RedGrittyBrick could amend their answer and other people could add more answers to cover other aspects, or we even merge some other questions into the topic to move their answers there.
Does someone have a better candidate or comments on how to proceed?

I closed I can withdraw my BTC on cryptoayo and they insisting on me to pay an amount ...?? How can one unlock block chain and be independent and withdraw? as a duplicate to it today already.

I have created a canonical question in which I attempt to better capture the scope of the questions: Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?
